# How to create simple and refactor-proof page links in my Tapestry 5 application?

Tags: java, tapestry

Suppose I have a `Grid` with some links to edit an `Entity`. This is my `.tml` file

```
<table t:id="personGrid">
    <!-- ... -->
    <p:editCell>
        <p t:id="edit">${person.lastName}</p>
    </p:editCell>
    <!-- ... -->
</table>
```

In my `.java` file i have this:

```
@Component(parameters = {"context=person.employeeNumber", "page=person/PersonPage"})
private PageLink edit;
```

This is succint and I do not have to write a lot of boilerplate code. The pitfall here is if I refactor either `employeeNumber` or `PersonPage`. It will no longer work and the worst part is that I won't have an error message.

I found out that I can use `PageRenderLinkSource` instead like this:

```
@Inject
private PageRenderLinkSource editPersonLink;
// ...
Object onActionFromEdit(String employeeNumber)
{
    return editPersonLink.createPageRenderLinkWithContext(PersonPage.class, employeeNumber);
}
```

This is quite nice. It does not come with much more boilerplate but it is refactor-proof.

My problem is that I still have to keep

```
@Component(parameters = {"context=person.employeeNumber", "page=PersonPage"})
private PageLink edit;
```

in my `.java` file otherwise Tapestry will complain about the missing `@Component`.

So my question is that how to achieve some refactor-proof parametrized page links without the boilerplate?

I'm using Tapestry 5.3.6.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like you are using a *PageLink* as an *ActionLink* and it's somehow weird that that works.

Also, another problem with this approach is that you end up having one more roundtrip to the server than what you need.

Try this instead:

```
@Inject
private PageRenderLinkSource renderLinkSource;

public Link getEditLink() {
    return renderLinkSource.createPageRenderLinkWithContext(PersonPage.class, person.getEmployeeNumber());
}
```

and then:

```
<a href="${editLink}">${person.lastName}</a>
```

BTW, this asumes that your grid has *"row=person"* in it